# How to send a signal to custom theme?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In Tizen it's very easy to send signals to my theme (EDC) from C/C++ code by `elm_layout_signal_emit`.

I have a genlist named `myList`, and I created a custom theme for it (with EDC):

```
group { "elm/genlist/base/mystyle";
   parts { ... }

   programs {
      program { "myprogram";
         source: "app";
         signal: "mysignal";
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

I'm applying this theme to `myList`: `elm_object_style_set(myList, "mystyle")`.

**What is the way to run the `myprogram` program with this genlist?**

I tried

- `elm_layout_signal_emit`: didn't work, but genlist might not be a layout, I'm not surprised.
- `elm_object_signal_emit`: didn't work, have no clue why not
- `edje_object_signal_emit`: didn't work, also have no clue why

Answer (score 1):

elm_object_signal_emit should works.
but I have a doupt about those theme is properly applied.
if you want to set the custom style to an object,
you must change the theme firstly.
you can extend your custom theme by calling
elm_theme_extension_add(NULL, your_edc_path); //NULL means default theme.
see more details on
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/component-custom/

and I wonder... you really want to change genlist not genlist_item.
if you want to change genlist widget theme, which is very rarely changed,
you need to copy scroller theme or default genlist theme,
as genlist is special type of scroller.
genlist styles are located in widgets/scroller.edc in https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/efl-theme-tizen-wearable

to make sure,
I tested simply signal changes in scroller.edc(genlist/default)

```
  part { name: "myrect"; type: RECT;
     description { state: "default" 0.0;
        visible: 0;
     }
     description { state: "show" 0.0;
        inherit: "default" 0.0;
        visible: 1;
        color: 255 0 0 255;
     }
  }
  program { name: "myprogram";
     signal: "mysignal";
     source: "app";
     action: STATE_SET "show" 0.0;
     target: "myrect";
  }
```

and send a signal,
elm_object_signal_emit(myList, "mysignal", "app");

which change the background color to red properly.